# OpenGL iOS screen coordinates to scene coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, coordinates, glkit

I'm using OpenGl to make a little Application and I have no idea how to get the `x , y` and `z` coordinates of a touch

For example:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[self view]];

float X = touchPoint.x;
float Y = touchPoint.y;

}
```

with this I only get the `x` and `y` coordinates ,but I need the `z` as well

Comment: You could query the Z-buffer if you have easy access to it. It really depends on what you mean by "Z" coordinate though, I assume you mean depth, but there is no depth to a touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read the z buffer on OpenGL ES. When I've needed to do this kind of 3D hit testing I've projected a 3d line through the scene and done the hit-testing myself.

For OpenGL on Retina devices you need to multiply x and y by the scale. To support iPhone 6+ you need to use nativeScale when available.

```
// Do this when setting up view controller and remember theScale.
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeScale)])
  theScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale];
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
  theScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
else 
  theScale = 1.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast responding